# how to find outward normal for robin codition

Tags: pde, finite-element, matlab, boundary-conditions

[image: My problem]

I wrote the code to fix this problem; now  I should validate it using a test function to see the error in my code. I can't figure out how starting from u can derive the function g on the edge, in particular I don't manage to compute the outward normal.

This is my code to calculate g: https://dpaste.de/hzYm (p,t,e are output of initmesh)

Comment: This has already been answered in http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10317/pde-problem-with-robin-boundary-condition